# Search by name and id in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql

I have to search on form with id and name also in asp.net,

what condition should i use to check the user is entered  id in text box id field or text box for name or should i use only 1 textbox for search by id and name too..

m using sql server 2005 for storing records.

thank u

Comment: You could check the .length but you can also search both in 1 texbox just what you want i suppose but if id's are always numeric and names aren't that might be a nice way.

Answer (score 1):

On your ASP.Net page, you can use a `RequiredFieldValidator` to make sure that the user has entered something in the textbox.

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please enter your user name." ControlToValidate="UserNameTextBox" Display="Dynamic" />
```

I would use one textbox and let the user enter either their username or ID.

Then you write a query on the database to `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users WHERE (UserName = @UserName) OR (UserID = @UserID)`. Something like that. If `COUNT` equals zero, there was no match. If `COUNT` is greater than zero, you have a match.

Comment: Don't know about OP's storedProc but @UserName and @UserID refers to the same value and so it should be generic like @SearchValue.

Comment: what about using popup window on search button ?how to use it..?

Answer (score 0):

Use a combo box with two values: ID, Name

Then when user types in textbox, you can check the value selected in combobox, to know whether he is searching by Id or Name